# How would I go upon writing some python code to copy files from one folder to another using python and Dropbox API?

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I am fairly new to Python and Dropbox API. How would I go upon writing some python code that copies all the files from a particular folder to another folder?

Comment: What research did you do as a part of this? Also, do you want to copy files from your local directory to the one in dropbox server?

Comment: I have been reading this: https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/files.html?highlight=copy#dropbox.files.GetCopyReferenceArg but I am heaving trouble implementing it. I am looking to copy one folder in dropbox to another folder also in dropbox. So far I have been able to get to the directory but not been able to copy any of it.

Comment: Show us your code so we can see how far you've gotten and offer suggestions to push you along.  Dropbox can be treated just like any other directory on your local filesystem.  Do you really want to use the custom Dropbox API, or would you rather use standard filesystem operations to copy files in to and out of your local Dropbox directory?

Comment: This should get you going.  https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2012/02/new-copy-ref-feature-and-update-to-the-delta-call/ . Essentially, you are on the right path, you get a copy-ref for source file and then do another API call as per the docs to https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/fileops/copy. That should do the trick. :)

Comment: Thanks! Current this is what I have. I've gotten things to copy but now they are copying to a new folder and renaming it Folder 2(1) and so on. If I try to disable auto_rename, it refuses to copy.

`code:
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(token)

id = dbx.users_get_current_account()

#print(id)

dbx.files_copy('/Folder1','/Folder2', allow_shared_folder=True, autorename=True, allow_ownership_transfer=True)
print('Moved file.')
print(entry.name)
`

Comment: are you sure that there is no folder with the same name?

Comment: Yes, there is. But that is the folder that I am trying to copy to. How do I make it not make a new folder?

Comment: try adding a slash after, something like /Folder2/

Comment: If it fixed your issue, I would be happy to submit it as answer and you can accept it. :)